# Http run time cache c# issue with list

Tags: c#, http, caching

I am adding items to cache like this

```
public void Put<T>(string key, T value, string region)
{
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(GetCacheKey(key, region),
    value, null, GetTtl(),
    DefaultSlidingExpiration);
}
```

I am putting a list of strings in the cache like this. The length of the list is 3. When I put it and get it right away then I get correct count and the cache has three items.

```
    public T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        return (T)HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(GetCacheKey(key));
    }
```

If I refresh the page then the cache has just 1 item.

I am calling the put cache method as

```
_udeCache.Put(key, value);
```

Where value is an object of type

> Guardian

which has a member list of strings. The issue is only with of strings. Caching list of strings is not working and the other object members are cached properly.

When I am getting I call like

```
_udeCache.Get<Guardian>(key);
```

Comment: You should box cachable things that are 'collection' type `IEnumerable<T>` into a type and cache the type instead.

Comment: Can I get any example?

Comment: Post your current usage of `Put<T>` method

Comment: Can you share the code which uses Put and Get methods of cache?

Comment: I have added the code for calling the put and get method. the issue only with list of strings. Is there any way to overcome that? Like some settings where I say that cache list of strings, because it just caches one item in list

Comment: You still haven`t outlined your issue properly. It's hard to understand exactly whats wrong for you... we're not mind readers.

Comment: The problem like I have said is that if I store List<strings> in cache they are not stored properly. They are truncated.